# LCM and GCD not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I made a program for codechef and its wrong apparantly (although all tests have been positive). The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int g (int a,int b){
    return b == 0 ? a : g(b, a % b);
}

int l (int a, int b){
    return (a*b)/(g(a,b));
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n],b[n];
    for (int x = 0;x<n;x++){
        cin >> a[x] >> b[x];    
    }
    for (int x = 0;x<n;x++){
        cout << g(a[x],b[x]) << " "<< l(a[x],b[x]) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Codechef won't  tell me what integers dont work, and im pretty sure my gcd function is legit.

Comment: Have you considered what would happen when `a` and/or `b` gets close to INT_MAX?

Comment: What do you mean by "its wrong apparantly (although all tests have been positive)"? Why is it wrong? What tests have been "positive"? Please provide more details about the specific problems you encounter.

Comment: @Frank The parameters for the problem lie under int max.

Comment: @AGNGazer All the tests i have done shown it to work, but the codechef judge says its wrong. There has to be something wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `gcd` is properly defined as the largest non-negative common divisor, you can save yourself the annoying details of signed division, e.g.,

```
static unsigned gcd (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    /* additional iteration if (a < b) : */
    for (unsigned t = 0; (t = b) != 0; a = t)
        b = a % b;

    return a;
}
```

Likewise for `lcm`; but the problem here is that `(a*b)` may overflow. So if you have two large (signed) int values that are co-prime, say: `2147483647` and `2147483629`, then `gcd(a,b) == 1`, and `(a*b)/g` overflows.

A reasonable assumption on most platforms is that `unsigned long long` is twice the width of `unsigned` - although strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be. This is also a good reason to use exact types like `[u]int32_t` and `[u]int64_t`.

One thing you can be sure of is that `a/g` or `b/g` will not cause any [issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Reduction_by_the_greatest_common_divisor). So a possible implementation might be:

```
static unsigned long long lcm (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    return ((unsigned long long) a) * (b / gcd(a, b)));
}
```

If your test values are 'positive' (which is what I think you mean), you can cast them prior to `(unsigned)` prior to call. Better yet - replace all your `int` variables with `unsigned int` (though the loop variables are fine), and save yourself the trouble to begin with.